# Closest solution to multiple inheritance through QObject subclasses

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, diamond-problem, moc

I have multiple QObject subclasses which should act as interface classes and be implemented by (inherited by) some other classes. For example let `class A : virtual public QObject` and  `class B : virtual public QObject` be interface classes. I need a `QDialog` object to implement their behavior like: `class X: public QDialog, A, B`.

Unfortunately I did not read documentation carefully at design time and now I realized two facts:

1. implementing slots as pure virtual member functions is not possible because moc-generated code will need to call them.
2. Multiple inheritance is not supported for QObject-derived classes. That's not a diamond thing. It's because moc-generated code can't `static_cast` a virtual `QObject` object to a `A*` via virtual base. (That's what compiler says!)

What is best possible alternative design to which affects code as less as possible? I can think of macro hacks. Maybe a macro in base class (like `Q_OBJECT`) to copy all members, signals, slots of base to derived class?

**Note** That's really bad that `QObject`s can't be inherited multiple times. Isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to expose `QObject` member functions through your `A` and `B` classes create an abstract base class (i.e. a class with only pure virtual member functions), say `AbstractQObject`, and re-declare there the `QObject` member functions you need to expose.

Have `A` and `B` derive virtually from `AbstractQObject` and `X` from `QDialog`, `A` and `B`.

This should solve the problem you described, but I suspect you would be better off redesigning your code.

Comment: No, that's not about `QObject` members. `A` and `B` uses signals and slots, so need to inherit `QObject` and declare `Q_OBJECT` macro inside class. For example `A` have a `QFutureWatcher` object running a thread and connected its `finished` signal to one of `A`s slots.

Comment: Then I'm afraid your only option is to try and reorganize your code so as to use composition and delegation rather than inheritance